# Xcode/iPhone: First Windows-Based Application - Why isn't anything showing up in the TabBarController views

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, tabbarcontroller

Is there something that I need to remember when using the windows-based template? Because I'm unclear as to why the tabs are showing up but nothing in the views are showing up.

Could you help? Because I've been searching through previous questions for a few hours now and I still haven't found anything to clear this up.

AnotherMadeUpAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AnotherMadeUpViewController.h"

@interface AnotherMadeUpAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AnotherMadeUpAppDelegate.m

```
#import "AnotherMadeUpAppDelegate.h"

@implementation AnotherMadeUpAppDelegate


@synthesize window=_window;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    AnotherMadeUpViewController *vc3 = [[AnotherMadeUpViewController alloc] init];

    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, nil];
    [vc1 release];
    [vc2 release];
    [vc3 release];

    [self.window addSubview:tbc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
...
@end
```

AnotherMadeUpViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AnotherMadeUpViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

    IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIPageControl *pageControl;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *label;

-(IBAction)clickPageControl:(id)sender;

@end
```

AnotherMadeUpViewController.m

```
#import "AnotherMadeUpViewController.h"

@implementation AnotherMadeUpViewController
@synthesize pageControl,scroller,label;

-(IBAction)clickPageControl:(id)sender
{
    int page=pageControl.currentPage;
    CGRect frame=scroller.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x/scrollView.frame.size.width;
    pageControl.currentPage=page;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [label release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;
    CGFloat labelOriginX = label.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat labelOriginY = label.frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat scrollWidth = 0;
    int pageNumber = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        CGRect rect = label.frame;
        rect.size.height = label.frame.size.height;
        rect.size.width = label.frame.size.width;
        rect.origin.x = labelOriginX + scrollWidth;
        rect.origin.y = labelOriginY;
        label.frame = rect;
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pageNumber];
        label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [scroller addSubview:label];
        pageNumber++;
        scrollWidth += scroller.frame.size.width;
    }
    scroller.delegate=self;
    scroller.directionalLockEnabled=YES;
    scroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator=NO;
    scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;
    pageControl.numberOfPages=9;
    pageControl.currentPage=0;
    scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(pageControl.numberOfPages*self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scroller];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [label release];
    self.label = nil;
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: Is there a NIB for `AnotherMadeUpViewController`? What's its name?

Comment: Hi Deepak. I have a AnotherMadeUpViewController.xib file ... is that what you're referring to? I'm not sure how to get the NIB version

Comment: Yes `NIB` and `XIB` are synonymous. Everything seems to be in order. The first two tabs wouldn't show anything as they are just `UIViewController` instances. What about the third tab? What is the expected behavior and what is it doing now?

Comment: Hmm, so it's working now. The only issue is the label isn't changing. (i.e., "Just show something" isn't working).

Comment: You need to set the frame of the label.

Comment: So I updated the code so that it displays a number as a string. Each "page" shows the same number as opposed to different numbers. Is that still a part of the frame?

Comment: int myInt = 5;
    for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
    {
        label.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt] stringValue];
        [scroller addSubview:label];
        myInt+=1;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dissecting your `viewDidLoad` –

```
scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

You seem to be creating a new scroll view instance here but you have **declared it as an outlet**. If you don't have an outlet then remove the `IBOutlet` tag for `scroller`. If you do have one and want to use it then remove the above line. A shorter way of doing it would be,

```
scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Another thing is that you are creating 10 labels but **assigning no frame**. To show one of them each in different page,

```
int pageNumber = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [label sizeToFit];
    label.center = CGPointMake (((2 * i + 1) * self.view.frame.size.width) / 2, self.view.frame.size.height / 2);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pageNumber];

    [scroller addSubview:label];
    [label release];

    pageNumber++;
}
```

and later set the `contentSize` to show 10 pages,

```
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(10 * self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Thanks again Deepak. I always appreciate your feedback! :-) And just for my clarification ... when declaring something as an outlet should I still create it in Interface Builder and simply not connect it? Or should I not create it in Interface Builder at all?

Comment: The purpose of declaring something as an outlet is to connect it to an interface item otherwise no point declaring it as such. Omit the `IBOutlet` if you don't want to connect it. `IBOutlet` is just an indicator for the IB. Another thing is that if you create an object in IB and don't connect it, its properties cannot be modified as you don't have reference to it.

Comment: Ah OK. So if I want to create a label in IB then I should 1) connect it via an IBOutlet and 2) get rid of the `UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];` code in the loop. Would I still need to assign a frame to the label if I build it in IB? Because I'm unsure of how `[label sizeToFit]`, `label.center = ...` and `[label release]` come into play if I go through the IBOutlet route. Or is it better avoiding the IBOutlet route for for loops?

Comment: If you create the label in the IB then you don't need the `alloc-init` and since you would've set the frame appropriately remove the `sizeToFit` and `.center` lines. You will need to release it but in `dealloc`. In `viewDidUnload`, you will have to do `self.label = nil;`.

Comment: Now, the problem with `UIScrollView` is that when the `contentSize` is bigger than its bounds size, you can't place it in parts that aren't visible i.e. outside the bounds.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I update my code and the code above to reflect what you suggested. I'm glad you pointed that out because I would have never messed with viewDidUnload and dealloc. Does the UIScrollView issue with contentSize affect the different label displays? Because all my labels still only show the same thing (i.e., a red'8').

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
AnotherMadeUpViewController *vc3 = [[AnotherMadeUpViewController alloc] init];
```

You need to change it to

```
AnotherMadeUpViewController *vc3 = [[AnotherMadeUpViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AnotherMadeUpViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Then your .xib will get loaded and your outlets will be connected.

And don't forget to connect your outlets to File's owner in IB.

Comment: I did implement it but in this case there wasn't a difference in the end result. Although that's probably because I've been messing with the code so much. But thank you again Uvesten.